# Signature of std::strtol

Tags: c++

The signature of `std::strtol` is formulated as follows:

`long strtol(const char *str, char **str_end, int base);`

I actually expect the second parameter to be of type `const char**`. Any explanation on why it is of type `char**` instead? Note that, it is possible to modify a variable of type `const char**`. What you cannot modify is a `char* const *` variable.

Comment: This function _changes the `str_end` pointer_, that's why it has to be just `char **`

Comment: Probably because that's how the function is declared in C, and C++ wants to be compatible. As for why it's declared like that in C, it's probably for backwards compatibility with old code. For the exact reason you have to ask the standards committee.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: That doesn't make much sense because the first parameter is `const`.

Comment: From the answers, I'm just surprised that many people do not correctly distinguish `const char**` from `char* const *`.

Comment: Billy ONeal.  Yes, but if I have `char foo[10] = "123z", *p; long l = strtol(foo, &p, 10); *p = 0;` I would expect it to work.  It's the same reason the C search functions take a `const char *`, but return a `char *`.

Comment: @Martin: Yeah, I had it backwards.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In the days of yore (before C90) C had no concept of `const` and everything used plain `char*`.

Since `char*` can be implicitly converted to a `char const*` changing the signature of most library functions to support `const` wasn't too much of an issue. `char**` however can't be converted to a `char const**`, see the following note from the C++ standard for why

[image]

Since C doesn't support overloading the committee had to choose between breaking legacy code, or forcing everyone to pass in a `char**`. Neither is ideal but it looks like they went with the latter.